# How to get user's tenant-id on a multi-tenant daemon application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Once the admin has consented to my daemon app he is redirected back to my website, but I want to be extra safe and attempt to get the user's tenant from his e-mail address. Is it possible to do so in any way using the `common` endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

•   Yes, you can get the user’s tenant name from the email address it uses to sign in with the ‘/common’ endpoint. Since, you are using a multi-tenant daemon application, the application doesn’t know up front what tenant the user is from, so you can’t send requests to a tenant’s endpoint. Instead, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants: -

```
      ' https://login.microsoftonline.com/common '
```

•   When the Microsoft identity platform receives a request on the /common endpoint, it signs the user in and, therefore, discovers which tenant the user is from. The /common endpoint works with all the authentication protocols supported by the Azure AD: OpenID Connect, OAuth 2.0, SAML 2.0, and WS-Federation. The sign-in response to the application then contains a token representing the user. The issuer value in the token tells an application what tenant the user is from. When a response returns from the ‘/common’ endpoint, the issuer value in the token corresponds to the user’s tenant.

•   The ‘/common’ endpoint is not a tenant and is not an issuer, it’s just a multiplexer. When using ‘/common’, the logic in your application to validate tokens needs to be updated to take this into account. Also, please take note that you cannot query the ‘/common’ endpoint and retrieve the user’s tenant name from its email address as it is passed as a credential grant claim to the Azure AD through the authentication protocols, however the redirection to the Azure AD platform is possible through the ‘/common’ endpoint only when the user logs in to the daemon app web api and the redirection is done internally by identifying the tenant name from the email address of the user.

Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common) document for more information.

Answer (score -1):

"Once the admin has consented to my daemon app he is redirected back to my website"

The redirect URL must have tenantId in it. 'tenant' is appended as a query parameter to the redirect URL once admin consent permissions.